# Hive Database file has no delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to read a HDFS file created by a HIVE table. The file is in text format. when I open the files I am surprised to see that the lines don't have any field delimiter.

Hive can read the files... but very very slowly. therefore I want to read the content using a spark job.

in order to understand the schema of the table I did a

```
describe extended foo
```

and I see this output

```
Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:foo, dbName:bar, owner:me, 
createTime:1456445643, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:
[FieldSchema(name:some_ts, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:id, 
type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:t_p_ref, type:string, 
comment:null) location:hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/bar.db/ft, 
inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, 
outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, 
compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, 
serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:
{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, 
skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], 
skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], 
parameters:{numFiles=79, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE=true, 
transient_lastDdlTime=1456446229, totalSize=8992777753, numRows=20776467, 
rawDataSize=8972001286}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, 
tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
```

So the output does not show "delim" at all. So how do I read this file?
some of the fields are URLs and therefore its quite hard to try to read it as a fixed width type of file

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but I cannot read it via hive context as they are on different server. I have extracted the dump and its in bz2 format. 
I am reading it as a textFile in spark. But there is no delimiter. Can Anyone help in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not read the data via spark sql - which is quite happy to read hive tables using a `HiveContext` ?  In that case you have the datatypes properly set up as well from the dataframe.

So something like

```
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = hc.sql("select * from foo limit 10")
// perform operations on your dataframe ..
```

Comment: won't that be equally slow? since it is still using Hive under the hoods.

Comment: No it does NOT use hive under the hood - only the Hive Metastore for the metadata. Spark can do the work with tens to hundreds of workers within the Spark computing framework which is faster than Hive.